# Can we pass two annotation(IRetryAnalyzer and priority) type as one in TestNG

Tags: java, testing, selenium-webdriver

I have a situation where want to use IRetryAnalyzer and priority at a single time for testcase as an example. I want to use/apply below two parameter to a single testcase

```
@Test(retryAnalyzer = test1.Retry.class)
@Test(priority=0)
```

Example :-

```
@Test(retryAnalyzer = test1.Retry.class)
@Test(priority=0)
public void Test1()
{
    System.out.println("Retry attempt");
    i++;
    System.out.println("value of i ="+i);
    if(i<2)
    {
        System.out.println("I m in fail Fail");
        Assert.assertEquals(false, true);
    }
    if(i>=2) {
        System.out.println("I m in fail pass");
        Assert.assertEquals(false, false);
    }
}
```

[image]

Is there any way where I can apply both to a single testcase.

Comment: Have you tried combining them in one Test annotation - @Test(retry...=.... , priority =....)

Comment: Thanks buddy .. Why I wasn't think about it.. lol .. it is working :D

Comment: You can add this as a answer. I will accept it ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combine both values into one `Test` annotation.

```
@Test(retryAnalyzer = test1.Retry.class, priority=0)
public void Test1()
```